# example of \if_true: \fi: \else \reverse_if:N

Tags: expl3, xparse

it seems `expl3` language is not yet very popular, i have not found even a single example of this test. I tried it but it fails. What i understood is that `\reverse_if:N <primitive conditional>` will check whether its argument is `True` or `False` and run what was defined next to `\if_false:` or what next to `\else:` appropriately.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\geometry{verbose,papersize={160mm,90mm}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ifelsetest{ m o }{
  Ltroiscommand~test \\
  optional~parameter~:~#2
  \if_false:
  false
  \else:
  else
  \fi:
  \reverse_if:N { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\ifelsetest{test} % #2 should be -NoValue-, therefore I suppose 'False'

\ifelsetest{test}[optarg~shouldtesttrue] % Anything elsethan -NoValue- should
                                         % be 'True' I suppose

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `should be -NoValue-, therefore I suppose 'False'`  No. `-NoValue-` is not a boolean

Comment: `\reverse_if:N`  has a `:N` argument which should therefore always be a single token never a brace group `\reverse_if:N { #2 }`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you were expecting this to work.  It seems like you were thinking to define the `\if \else \fi`, and then have `\reverse` go back and change it around.  TeX doesn't really "go back".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function with argument spec `:N` expects to receive a single token as argument, so `\reverse_if:N { #1 }` isn't legal.

Actually, `\reverse_if:N` is an alias to the primitive `\unless`. If you look about it in `interface3`, you see

[image]

This means that the argument of `\reverse_if:N` *must* be one of the primitive conditionals described in section 4.6.2, namely

```
\if_true:  \if_false:  \if_meaning:w  \if:w  \if_catcode:w  \if_charcode:w
\if_cs_exist:N  \if_cs_exist:w  \if_mode_(...)
```

(the last comprises the four conditionals for testing the typesetting mode) and also

```
\if_int_compare:w  \if_dim:w
```

Anything else following `\reverse_if:N` would produce an error.

On the other hand, direct usage of these conditionals and of `\reverse_if:N` is not encouraged for writing functions and higher level programming is recommended. These primitive conditionals are admittedly faster, but they should only be used when the code has to be streamlined for efficiency, which is not so frequent a circumstance.

Thus seeing code with `\else:` or `\fi:` should be very rare. Look at the sections about boolean variables and functions.

If you want that your `\ifelsetest` prints “true” when the optional argument is present, you should use the `xparse` features:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifelsetest}{mo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{False}{True}%
}

\ifelsetest{text} % prints False

\ifelsetest{text}[whatever] % prints True
```

Comment: I think your last solution (`\IfNoValueTF`) is what i needed in this context.

Answer (score 5):

`\reverse_if:N` reverses a primitive conditional. That is, `\reverse_if:N \if_true:` behaves like `\if_false:` and `\reverse_if:N \if_false:` like `\if_true:`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\if_true: true~branch \else: false~branch \fi:

\par

\reverse_if:N \if_true: true~branch \else: false~branch \fi:

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

You can search for eTeX's `\unless` for examples in the non-LaTeX3 syntax.

Comment: I see, it's clear. But now since there is no argument test i don't see the purpose of these commands.

Comment: @user1850133 Well, it basically serves the same purpose as the `not` in Python's `if not`. An introduction into TeX programming is outside the scope of this answer, though. You can have a read in chapter 20 of the TeXbook for in-depth information on the primitive conditionals.